# Thevenin with coupled coils

Tags: thevenin

I'm trying to solve this problem (to find the equivalent thevenin):

[image: Thevenin figure]
[image]

where Xm (the mutual inductance) is 6 ohms.

I've solve this circuit with nodal analysis, but I would like to solve it without is as well. Here is what I've done so far:

- With nodal analysis:
  [image]

The numbers boxed are the solutions to Uth and Zth. The inverse of the matrix [H] is:
[image]

- Non-nodal analysis: as you can see, I obtain the same Uth, but not the same Zth. I know beforehand that the current solution is the one obtained by the nodal analysis.

[image]

Can anyone help me? I don't know what I'm doing wrong... Sorry for my bad english and thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `3i` meant to represent in terms of impedance?

Comment: The Thevenenin equivalent impedance, or so i i was said in class, as: Zth=Z_{3,0}=H^-1{3,3}.